# Java JCreator List reference to reference ArrayList not working?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello I've been trying to use the List reference to reference the ArrayList using the following code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Purse 
{
    private List<String> purseList;
    public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    // constructs an ArrayList of Strings
    public Purse()
    {
        purseList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

This gives me back the error

```
"Purse.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        purseList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class Purse
1 error"
```

But when I use this set of code there's no problem, what can I do to use List instead of ArrayList

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Purse 
{
    private ArrayList<String> purseList;
    public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    // constructs an ArrayList of Strings
    public Purse()
    {
        purseList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just import both `List` and `ArrayList`!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Purse 
{
    private List<String> purseList;
    public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    // constructs an ArrayList of Strings
    public Purse()
    {
        purseList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```